# Cannot install angular/cli in windows. Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\bin\postinstall\script.js

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, angular-cli

As mentioned in the title, when i try to install angular/cli using the command

> npm install -g @angular/cli

on my windows machine, I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\bin\postinstall\script.js

I am using node-v: v10.16.0
and npm-v: 6.9.0

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about nove, but the way I work with Angular is I install latest version of node and yarn then use yarn to check if angular cli installed is the latest version if not I remove it, then install the newest version from there I chose a working directory and use angular cli to install the webapp
(yarn global list ) (yarn global remove @angular/cli)  (yarn global add @angular/cli ) (ng new helloApp --prefix bob)